# Storyboard: Button image different on navigation and toolbar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, uistoryboard

I have an iPad storyboard with both a view containing a navigation bar and a toolbar. I have added a button item to both of them with the same image. But when running the application the image in the button seems a bit different in the two bars. Does someone have an explanation for this?

Here is the two buttons. The left is a toolbar with a bar button item and the right is a navigation item with a bar button item. The right one looks as it should.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you mind posting screenshots?